# Matrix Representation of Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

In my readings I have on several occasions encountered references to a linear algebra theorem that runs as follows:

Let $g$ be a non-degenerate inner product on the real vector space $V$. Then, there exists a basis $e_1, \dots, e_n$ such that the matrix of $g$ is diagonal and whose diagonal entries are all either $-1$ or $1$

Despite having encountered this result several times, unfortunately, I have not had the luck of finding a precise reference to where this theorem is stated/proved. Can anyone provide a reference that proves this claim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a really well-known result, so I am a bit surprised you can't find it. Any decent book on (general) algebra should have it. For example Lang's Algebra, Ch. XV ['Structure of Bilinear Forms'](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&pg=PA577&dq=symmetric%20forms%20over%20ordered%20fields). Or Knapp's Basic Algebra, [Symmetric Bilinear Forms](http://books.google.com/books?id=KVeXG163BggC&pg=PA252&dq=sylvester%27s%20law%20the%20signature). Or Mac Lane and Birkhoff's Algebra, Chapter on [Quadratic forms](http://books.google.com/books?id=piwKmqalFswC&pg=PA348&dq=sylvester%27s%20law%20signature).

As André said, this is often cited as Sylvester's Law of Inertia, and the pair (or triple) of numbers of +1,-1 (and 0's) is called the signature. So the words `sylvester law inertia signature` should lead you to relevant search results.

\Edit: Let me add to Qiaochu's answer a proof of well-definedness of the signature. It seems this one is a bit more elegant than one finds in most books.

So we know of an orthogonal decomposition $V=V_+\oplus V_-$, with our nondegenerate form $B$ positive resp. negative definite on $V_+$ resp. $V_-$. Say they have dimension $p,q$ respectively. If $W$ is any subspace of $V$ on which $B$ is positive definite, then $B$ is both positive and negative definite on $W\cap V_-$, hence $W\cap V_-=0$. This implies $\dim W\leq \dim V-q=p$. Hence $p$ is the maximal dimension of subspaces on which $B$ is positive definite; so $p$ only depends on the form $B$.

(If the form is degenerate, the number of zeros is just the kernel, and $p+q$ is the rank.)

Comment: Well, I didn't know what to call it so I had a rather hard time searching for it. Thank you for the multiple references.

Answer (score 10):

A slight correction: [inner products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) are <strike>always</strike> usually positive definite so there is always a basis relative to which the matrix representing the product is the identity matrix (diagonal with all $1$'s). What you are asking about is the fact that every [non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) over the reals can be represented relative so some basis by a matrix that is the identity matrix.

This follows immediately from [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Since the bilinear form $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric, we can define two vectors to be orthogonal if $(x,y)=0$.

Then picking an arbitrary basis and running Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization gives you an orthonormal basis relative to that form, i.e. a basis $\{v_i\}$ such that $(v_i,v_j)=0$ if $i\neq j$ and $||(v_i,v_i)||=1$. Then since the matrix $M=(m_{ij})$ representing $(\cdot,\cdot)$ relative to a basis $\{v_i\}$ has the property that $m_{ij}=(v_i,v_j)$
(since $(v_i,v_j)=(v_i^TMv_j)$), it follows that $M$ is diagonal with non-zero entries of norm $1$. But over the reals, non-zero number of norm $1$ are $\{1,-1\}$.

---

This all generalizes to symmetric bilinear forms (degenerate ones have a bunch of $0$'s along the diagonal) over arbitrary fields, except that if you don't have a norm you can't normalize the basis so that all the vectors would have norm $1$.

Note that over the complex number, the inner product is NOT a symmetric bilinear form, but a conjugate-symmetric bilinear form; Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization has to be modified accordingly, but can still be made to work.

Comment: Some people use 'inner product' for a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form, and say 'positive definite inner product' for the 'usual' inner product.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably referring to Sylvester's Law of Inertia.  Maybe search directly for that.  However, I would suggest first looking into the theorem that says a *symmetric matrix is diagonalizable*.  A proof is in almost all beginning Linear Algebra books, and you can find information on the Web in the usual places.

The whole thing is a generalization of the familiar "completing the square" procedure.

Comment: Knowing that a symmetric matrix is diagonalizable is not enough. You need to know that a symmetric matrix is _orthogonally_ diagonalizable, and that is a stronger result than you need to prove the law of inertia, which is a statement about matrices up to the equivalence relation $A \equiv M^T AM$, not the equivalence relation $A \equiv M^{-1} AM$.

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: I did not know exactly what was wanted, since *inner product* was one of the key words mentioned, but it came accompanied by the confusing $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a proof. Let $B : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a symmetric bilinear form. It suffices to show by induction that we can write $V = \text{span}(v) \oplus W$ for some nonzero vector $v$ such that $B(v, w) = 0$ for any $w \in W$ and such that $B(v, v) = 0, 1, -1$.

Choose an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ on $V$ (unrelated to $B$) and let $S^{n-1}$ denote its unit sphere. Let $v \in S^{n-1}$ be such that $B(v, v)$ is maximal. Let $w$ be a unit vector orthogonal to $v$; then

$$B(v + tw, v + tw) = B(v, v) + 2t B(v, w) + t^2 B(w, w) \le (1 + t^2) B(v, v)$$

by hypothesis, hence $2 B(v, w) \le t(B(v, v) - B(w, w))$. Taking $t = 0$ gives $B(v, w) \le 0$, and applying this result to $-w$ gives $B(v, w) = 0$. Depending on the value of $B(v, v)$ we can rescale $v$ so that $B(v, v) = 0, 1, -1$ and take $W$ to be the orthogonal complement of $v$ (with respect to the inner product).

Taking $B = \langle v, Aw \rangle$ where $A$ is symmetric and positive-definite, the intuitive content of the above proof is that $v$ is an axis of the ellipse $B(v, v) = 1$. Note that I haven't actually proven the full content of the law of inertia, which states in addition that the number of times $0, 1, -1$ appears doesn't depend on the choice of decomposition.